# SQL Select where found match value in column

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to retrieval data from mysql db that match part of string without using "LIKE"?
for example I have a column with value of "22,56,79,45,69"
and I want to retrieval only the rows that the number "45" ןs inside the column value without using "LIKE" condition ?

some thing like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE 45 is part of value in Column_Name
```

Is it possible or I have to use "LIKE" ?

Comment: And why can't you use `LIKE`?

Comment: Because if I am retrieval all the data LIKE 30 I get results of 30 - 300 - 3000 etc ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you *cannot* change your schema, the `LIKE` operator would be the easiest way to do this.

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE
Column_Name LIKE '45,%'      -- Starts with 45
OR Column_Name LIKE '%,45,%' -- 45 in the middle somewhere
OR Column_Name LIKE '%,45'   -- Ends with 45
OR Column_Name = '45';       -- 45 is the only item in the list
```

You could also perhaps simplify this as:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE concat(',',Column_Name,',') LIKE '%,45,%';
```

I would recommend *against* this approach if your table is large though, and performance is a concern.  MySql won't be able to take advantage of an index for this.  Instead, I'd recommend normalizing your data.  Put each value in a separate row in a different table, and `JOIN` on that table instead.  This would be considerably faster.

To answer your *actual* question of whether or not this is possible with your current schema and without using `LIKE`, you could check into the [Regexp operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp).  However, I don't really see this being any different than using `LIKE`.  It will still have to parse each string in the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you will have less than 100 items in your comma-separated list, you can use a CTE to "un-roll" that into a table...

http://www.wisesoft.co.uk/scripts/t-sql_cte_split_string_function.aspx

Comment: This doesn't apply to mySQL.  (Yes, the question is poorly tagged)

Comment: Ugh... well, maybe some real software developers will appreciate the technique :)